# Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.getVariantManager()

Tags: android, android-studio, github, timer, android-gradle-plugin

Error: Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.getVariantManager() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

I have error with opened project from github. First, I wanted to launch app by pressing "Play" button, then button greyed out and then became green again, then I saw notification to upgrade Gradle plugin, I pressed it and now I'm getting this error.

Here is project I'm trying to launch: https://github.com/AkshayChordiya/timer-kotlin-sample

How to solve these problems?